# Convergence of Gibbs distribution to Dirac measure

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, calculus-of-variations

Consider the probability density function on $R^d$ for a continuous function $F: R^d \to R$:
$$
q_{\varepsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{Z} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\varepsilon} F(x)\right).
$$

Denote $x^* = \arg \min_{x \in R^n} ~ F(x)$ the unique global minimizer of $F$ (assumed to exist).

Does $q_{\varepsilon} \to \delta_{x^*}$ for $\varepsilon \to 0$ in the sense that
$$
\int q_{\varepsilon}(x) \varphi(x) dx = \varphi(x^*),
$$
for all compactly supported test functions $\varphi \in C_c(R^d)$?

EDIT: I was unaware this is apparently well-known. Should be moved to math.stackexchange.

Comment: Yes this is called the Laplace principle in large deviation. But perhaps this question is better suited for math.StackExchange.